# having errors in my project for java

Tags: java

so im done with the whole thing and i compile it when i ran it it had a error for said: arrayindexexception and i try looking for my mistake and i could not find it so i need someone to see if they can help me

```
public class Merging
{

    public static int[] merge(int[] arrA, int[] arrB)
    {
        int[] sum = new int[arrA.length + arrB.length];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        while ( i < arrA.length && j < arrB.length)
        {
            if(arrA[i] < arrB[j])
            {
                sum[k] = arrA[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }else
                sum[k] = arrB[i];
                j++;
                k++;
        }
        return sum;

    }  
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a = (int)(Math.random() * (50-20+1)+20);
        int b = (int)(Math.random() * (50-20+1)+20);

        int[] a1 = new int[a];
        int[] a2 = new int[b];

        int i = 0;
        while(i < a1.length && 1 < a2.length)
        {
            a1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (150-20+1)+20);
            a2[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (150-20+1)+20);
            i++;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < a1.length; j++)
        {
        System.out.print(a1[j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int k = 0; k < a2.length; k++)
        {
        System.out.print(a1[k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(merge(a1,a2));             
    }
}
```

Comment: **Be specific.**  *What* exactly was the error, and *where* exactly was it occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors.

1.) Change from `1 < a2.length` to `i < a2.length`

```
 while (i < a1.length && i < a2.length) {
            a1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (150 - 20 + 1) + 20);
            a2[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (150 - 20 + 1) + 20);
            i++;
        }
```

2.) Change from  `System.out.print(a1[k]);` to  `System.out.print(a2[k]);`

```
 for (int k = 0 ; k < a2.length ; k++) {
            System.out.print(a2[k]);
        }
```

Comment: Yea i just didnt check my work well, because i had to turn it in before 9pm or you lose a point, so i rush and did not check it. Thanks

Comment: @chilithewilly pls accept/upvote the answer if it solves your purpose

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop

```
while(i < a1.length && 1 < a2.length)
```

the "1" should be an "i"

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is here

```
for(int k = 0; k < a2.length; k++)
{
    System.out.print(a1[k]);
}
```

You're iterating through `a1`, but your index goes to the length of `a2`.